# Python Virtual Environment Variables Not Saving

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment for python and need to add some variable.  I use

```
$set USERNAME = my_username
```

but when I close the cmd and re-open, the variable is gone.  I read in Super User that closing the cmd is necessary here https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt.

How do I save the variable so that it is still there after I deactivate my VE, then close out the cmd?

(I have tried doing this as both a user and admin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Windows + R, type in `sysdm.cpl` and hit enter. You should now see a prompt titled "System Properties". Click on Advanced -> Environment Variables. You can see all the environment variables that are set on your machine. Hit add and add your USERNAME environment variable and set it to your value

Comment: Ahh okay, didn't realize this wasn't something you could do from the command line.  This is for my actual environment though, is there a way to do this for my virtual environment I created using virtualenv?

Comment: When you set it in the prompt, it's only for that session. Setting it this way makes it persistent

Comment: Okay that's what I expected, but wanted to make sure.  Thanks!